# Clicking links on Safari using ctrl + F

Tags: keyboard, safari

I am looking for a convenient method to navigate safari (mainly clicking links) using keyboard only. I'm already familiar with the `Tab` key (or `opt` + `Tab`), but I noticed that in Chrome and Firefox you can `ctrl`+`F`, type the text of the like you with to click, after highlighting the link, you can click `esc` (the link keeps being highlighted) and press `return` to navigate the URL.

Is there a way to configure this in Safari? or any other way of being able to click links?

The problem of the `Tab` option is that many times it requires clicking on it many many times until getting to the desired link.

Comment: It works for bing, on safari. I can get to the the word "Apple (<country>)" by cmd + f and then hit enter

Answer (score 0):

Using Vimari (Safari extension - link below) one can press `f` then all links on the page are assigned by letters which you can use to access each. This is very convenient and can save a lot of mouse time.

This extension provides other vim style keybindings that I found really useful (page scrolling, tabs navigation and focusing on input fields)

[Vimari GitHub page](https://github.com/televator-apps/vimari)